# Libgdx - ADs for android

Tags: android, libgdx

Just completed my game so now I have to implements ads. And I can see there is AdMob? So I use that? But then I saw there is like alot of implementing to do. Does anyone maybe have an already completed code, since the code is probably the same for every game? Or any pointers on how to implement the AdMob fast?

Comment: If you want persistent banner ads throughout your game, it's easy. You can instantiate your LibGDX game as a View (see the Libgdx wiki) and combine it with an AdView in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ok, so I can just copy someone elses AdView and change what I need to. Know of any AdView code already made?

Comment: AdView comes with the AdMob SDK. I'm sure various other ad networks provide something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this [Github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) Just take 10 minutes.